# Trying to understand the logic behind the PHP parser / functions

Tags: php, function, logic

Say I have this `b.php` file

```
<?php 
   function ff() { echo "B"; }
```

and this `a.php` file

```
<?php 

if ( true ) {
  include ("b.php");
  ff();
  exit;
}

function ff() { echo "A"; }
```

Running `php a.php` gives

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare ff()
```

Hmm, ok. So what if I re-run `php a.php` with this `a.php` code

```
<?php 

if ( true ) {
  include ("b.php");
  ff();
  exit;
}
else {
  function ff() { echo "A"; }
}
```

This time that works, and I get `B` as expected.

In the first case, PHP reads and parse the whole file. Meaning, during *compilation* it sees the 2 same functions declarations, though the `exit` guarantees that at runtime we won't get up to the 2nd `ff()`.

However in the 2nd case, it sees it at *run* time, but the compiler is not upset about seeing this function declared twice...

Seems the compiler behaves differently based on if the function is top-level or not... while

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope

(the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php))

Now, how to turn that into a non opinion-based question :)
So it seems the options are either to rename `ff` to something like `ffa` and `ffb`, or add a long `else { ... }`. or change the whole structure...

Is this how PHP works, or that can be changed in the settings?

Comment: `though the exit guarantees that at runtime we won't get up to the 2nd ff()` ... actually I'd suspect that the `else` is a more significant factor - the compiler probably realises that both definitions of the function cannot exist at the same time - they don't exist unless the code enters the block that declares them, and the code cannot enter enter both blocks (example #3 in your documentation link shows a related scenario where a function doesn't exist until it's created by another piece of code.)

Comment: Whereas in your first example the function is always declared in both cases, so it's immediately obvious to the compiler that there's a clash. The quotation about scope isn't really relevant, it's about whether the functions will actually come to exist or not. I don't know if this for certain (hence comment not answer) but it seems logical